# at the time of billing ,customer creation screen should opens every time no matter what value is there in database property table

Tags: sql, screen, creation

, i am getting customer screen for walkin customer but i am not getting this screen for existing customer,please help me 
here is the if condition code

```
if (customerData[25].equalsIgnoreCase
                (Configuration.getParameter(ConfigSetting.CUSTOMER_EDIT_CRITERIA))  
                || iCalledfromSearch
                || (Configuration.getParameter(ConfigSetting.CUSTOMER_EDIT_CRITERIA))
                    .equalsIgnoreCase("NA") )
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to add one more condition as below
(Configuration.getParameter(ConfigSetting.CUSTOMER_EDIT_CRITERIA))
                    .equalsIgnoreCase("Y") )